# why is - (null) at the end of my object

Tags: objective-c, class, null

I have the following class

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface UIImageViewInfo : UIImageView
@property(nonatomic,strong) NSString* colorInfo;
@end
```

when creating an UIImageViewInfo in function1(post below) I get the correct result

> "UIImageViewInfo: 0x1d8acd60; baseClass = UIImageView; frame = (0 0;
>   20 20); opaque = NO; userInteractionEnabled = NO; tag = 2000; layer =
>   CALayer: 0x1d8a0560>>"

but creating the something in function2(posted below) I get the -(null)

> UIImageViewInfo: 0x8372c40; baseClass = UIImageView; frame = (0 0; 20
>   20); alpha = 0; hidden = YES; opaque = NO; userInteractionEnabled =
>   NO; tag = 2000; layer = CALayer: 0x8380090>> - (null)

Why is there a - (null) ??

Thanx in advance

P.S> here is more from my code

```
-(void)function1{
UIImageViewInfo *image;
self.solutionPinSlots = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

for (int i=0; i<M; i++) {
    image = [[UIImageViewInfo alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"solutionPeg@2x.png"]];
    image.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints=NO;

    image.hidden=YES;
    image.alpha = 0;
    image.colorInfo = @"clear";

    image.tag = 2000*(self.brainController.slotsIndex+1) +i;
    [self.solutionPinSlots addObject:image];
    [self.view addSubview:(UIImageViewInfo *)self.solutionPinSlots[i]];
}
NSLog(@"solutionSlots: %@",self.solutionPinSlots);
__block int counter = 0;
[self.brainController.solution enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(NSString *peg, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop){

    for (int i=0;i<M;i++) {
        if ([self.brainController.slots[self.brainController.slotsIndex][i] isEqual:peg]) {

            if (i==idx) {
             ((UIImageViewInfo *) self.solutionPinSlots[counter]).backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
              ((UIImageViewInfo *) self.solutionPinSlots[counter]).colorInfo=@"white";
            }else{
                ((UIImageViewInfo *) self.solutionPinSlots[counter]).backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
                ((UIImageViewInfo *) self.solutionPinSlots[counter]).colorInfo=@"black";}
            ((UIImageViewInfo *) self.solutionPinSlots[counter]).hidden=NO;
            ((UIImageViewInfo *) self.solutionPinSlots[counter++]).alpha=1;
        }
    }

}];

[self.solutionPinSlots shuffle];

[self updateSolutionPinSlots];
```

}

```
-(void)function2{
NSString *obj;


for (int idx=0; idx< M;idx++ ) {
    UIImageViewInfo *image = [[UIImageViewInfo alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"solutionPeg@2x.png"]];
    image.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints=NO;
    obj = (NSString *) [self.solutionPinSlots objectAtIndex:idx];
    image.tag=2000*(self.brainController.slotsIndex+1)+idx;
    image.hidden=NO;
    image.alpha = 1;
    if ([obj isEqualToString:@"clear"]) {
        image.hidden=YES;
        image.alpha = 0;
        image.colorInfo=@"clear";
        image.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
    }else if ([obj isEqualToString:@"white"]){
        image.colorInfo=@"white";
        image.backgroundColor=[UIColor whiteColor];
    }else if ([obj isEqualToString:@"black"]){
        image.colorInfo=@"black";
        image.backgroundColor=[UIColor blackColor];
    }else{
        NSLog(@"Something is Wrong!!!");
    }

    [self.solutionPinSlots replaceObjectAtIndex:idx withObject:image];

    [self.view addSubview:image];
}
```

}

Comment: Post your -description method's implementation.

Comment: I dnot have one, Im relying on the superclass which is UIImageView in my case.

Answer (score 2):

Never mind.  It is coming from the `description` method of UIView, which is rather complex and dumps a bunch of information about the view.   One of the conditionals is being tripped up by your configuration and causing the `(null)` at the end.

Safe to ignore.

<strike>There is no `UIImageViewInfo` class in UIKit, so the implementation must be in your project.  In that implementation, there is likely a `description` method that is implemented something like:</strike>

```
- (NSString*)description {
    ....
    return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"UIImageViewInfo:%p; %@ - %@", self, [super description], someInstanceVariableThatHappensToBeNil]];
}
```

Only your `description` is likely more complex due to the sometimes does this sometimes that output.

Not that you should not prefix classes with `UI` when subclassing the UIKit.

Comment: UIImageViewInfo is my class not in UIKit. I will post both my functions

Comment: @mjeragh Yeah -- don't prefix your classes w/UI.  Reserved for Apple and it makes your code very confusing for someone else to read.  Obviously, not the issue here, but...

Comment: Your answer is correct. Im surprised why they closed the question.

Comment: Been a lot of that going on;  it was a valid question, if a bit off the mark in details.  But off the mark in details is to be expected from someone that is learning.

Answer (score 1):

It is because your NSLog call (which you do not show) is asking for a second object, and that second object is null.

Comment: Thankx for your quick answer, but I am not using NSLog i am printing this info from the lldb console using PO

Comment: Then, as bbum says, this is an artifact of your class's `description` method. But the answer is still the same: the `description` method asks for and tries to represent some second object which is null.